# Formik and validation

Tags: reactjs, formik-material-ui

So i'm wondering if I maybe am not using `formik` properly and my expectation on what it can do is incorrect. Basically I have a form I'm wanting to validate on certain fields and all is good until I need to validate a `TextField` that is multi-lined. I have two ways of solving this problem but need a bit of direction on if this is possible. I'll provide the code examples.

```
const validateCompetitors = (values, props) => {
    const errors = {};
    let errorIndex = [];
    const competitors = values && values.split('\n');

    if (!competitors) {
      errors.competitors = 'Enter competitor urls please';
    } else {
      competitors.map((url, idx) => {
        if (!/^((https?|ftp):\/\/)?(www.)?(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i
          .test(url)) {
          errorIndex = [...errorIndex, idx + 1];
          errors.competitors = `Provided url is incorrectly formated on line(s) ${errorIndex.map((error) => `${error}`)}`;
        }
      });
    }
    return errors;
  };
       <Formik
          validateOnBlur={false}
          validateOnChange={false}
          initialValues={{
             competitors: ''
           }}
           onSubmit={(values, {errors}) => console.log(values, errors)}
           >
          {({

            errors,
            values
          }) => (
            <Form
              noValidate
              onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
               <TextField
                  name="competitors"
                  error={errors.competitors}
                  value={values.competitors}
                  multiline
          onKeyPress={(e) => e.key === 'Enter' && validateCompetitors(values.competitors)}
                  error={errors.competitors}
              value={values.competitors}
                />
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  fullWidth
                  type="submit"
                  to="#"
                >
                  Add website
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </Form>
          )}
       </Formik>
```

I'm currently firing the validation on enter press in `TextFeild`. I've also tried it every way basically that's on formiks docs and still am not able to validate. The `validateCompetitors` does return an object with `errors.competitors`. I was maybe thinking of replacing the multilined TextField with a single TextField and an option to add more field to validate with a plus button or something, but even then how would dynamic validation work as each field would need a identifying name correct? Current set up is from the other dev i'm working with and i'm just trying to solve what he assigned me.

Thanks

Comment: Won't adding <FormErrorMessage name="competors" /> after field show the error?

Comment: Ooh nice! I didn't realize I can add a Error handler like that. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to replace your Textfield with Field
ex :

```
 <Field  component='textarea'
                  name="competitors"
                  error={errors.competitors}
                  value={values.competitors}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onKeyPress={(e) => e.key === 'Enter' && validateCompetitors(values.competitors)}
                  error={errors.competitors}
                  value={values.competitors}
                />
```